# Using a dot for variable declaration in C

Tags: c

I read a code online and the next line caught my attention since I don't know why does it have a "." after the 0:

```
variable=0.;
```

I couldn't find the answer after looking for it. Could you please tell me what is the dot for?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot makes it a `double`. A clearer way to write it is `0.0`.